# Operation on function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Given $f(x)= \{ (0,1), (1,2), (2,3) \}$ and $g(x)= \{ (1,0), (2,4), (4,-5) \}$, find:
>
> $1. ~~(f + g)(2)$.
>
> $2. ~~ (f + g)(x)$ and its domain.

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please avoid expressions such as "Please help me!!!" because everyone who is here is here to help each other. Also it would be nice if you learned basic LaTeX to format your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $f(x)=\{(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)\}$ can be understood as $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=3$. You do the same for $g(x)$. What does $(f+g)(x)$ mean? It means $f(x)+g(x)$. Now you should be able to solve part 1. For part 2, you need to see where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined.

Answer (score 1):

What you don't understand here is that $f(x) = \{(0, 1)\}$, for example, means that $f(0) = 1$. Now you can check that $f(2) + g(2) = 3 + 4$.